# List all .txt file and count number of column

Tags: awk

How to list all the .txt files (pipe delimited file) and the number of columns of each file in a directory?

Comment: post how should look the expected result

Comment: name and number of columns in that file.

Comment: elaborate your question whether it should find all text files recursively

Comment: it must list all the text files and number of columns in each text file

Comment: again, specify whether each filename should contain the full path

Comment: just file name (same directory) and number of columns will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -size +0 -exec awk -F '|' '
  FNR == 1 {print FILENAME ": " NF; nextfile}' {} +
```

Would print something like

```
./dir/foo.txt: 2
```

for each regular non-empty file whose name ends in `.txt` where `"2"` is the number of `|`-separated fields in the first line of the file.

Note that `nextfile` is not available in all `awk` implementations, but in those where it's not, it should be harmless (just less efficient as `awk`  would read the files fully).

If you wanted to consider only the files that have the same number of columns in all their non-empty lines, with GNU `awk`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -size +0 -exec awk -F '|' '
  BEGINFILE {n = 0}
  NF {
    if (n && NF != n) {
      print "skipping "FILENAME" ("NF" != "n")" > "/dev/stderr"
      n = 0; nextfile
    }
    n = NF
  }
  ENDFILE {if (n) print FILENAME ": " n}' {} +
```

Comment: this worked out

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, well, a file without pipes is also a pipe-separated file with only one column. I'm skipping empty files (with `-size +0` but `FNR == 1` would also take care of it) as the number of columns is not defined there.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for any **awk** implementation:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec awk -F'|' 'NF{ print FILENAME,NF; exit }' {} \;
```

---

- `-F'|'` - treat `|` as field separator
- `NF{ ... }` - ensures that there's at least one field/column in the file. `NF` itself points to the number of columns

Comment: perfect. getting the results...

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't very clear but you can try this command:
`find DIRECTORY -name "*.txt" | xargs awk -F "SEPARATOR" "{print FILENAME, NF }"`
just replace `DIRECTORY` and `SEPARATOR` with your directory and column separator.

Comment: this is giving out the number of columns, but I need the name of file along with it.
example:  File name |||    number of columns

Comment: @SrijithA.H i see i didn't know you wanted it to print filename if you want to print filename alongside it just add FILENAME in the print argument check the example i gave above

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Comment: this is giving number of rows; instead I need number of columns (field)